# How to use webpack encore with sylius?

Tags: symfony, e-commerce, sylius, webpack-encore

Here is my problem, I am trying to create an e-commerce with the sylius framework which itself is based on symfony.
In the documentation, it says that the best way to download assets and therefore personalize your store is
to use webpack encore. So I followed the steps described in the doc by having `composer require symfony / webpack-encore-bundle`
then `yarn install` but unfortunately, when I have to do `yarn encore dev`, I have a problem. Note that at the time of `yarn install`, dependencies do not install correctly.
After doing research on the net, I understood that there is a conflict between yarn and gulp which is installed by default in sylius and that to correct the problem,
you must erase all traces of gulp. Personally i think this should not be the responsibility of neophytes. I found on github a branch of sylius without gulp called bye-bye-gulp I tried to clone it but impossible to work with.
If there are people who know how to hack this problem or better, people who have already passed this stage, please come to my aid.
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO Markus,

This is not a proper question for stack overflow, please read the guidelines. You might want to post your different webpack.config.js (the one in your theme folder too) to start with so we at least have some code to look at. It worked pretty easily for me on my current project based on Sylius 1.7, what tutorial are you using ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I had actually read that version 1.7 corrected the problem by integrating webpack encore. However, all my attempts to access version 1.7 were unsuccessful. Indeed, I download the project following the indications of the official Sylius documentation with the command composer create-project sylius/sylius-standard MyFirstShop. How did you do get the 1.7?

Comment: You need to follow: https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/UPGRADE-1.7.md watch out that it requires php 7.3+ tho

Comment: And generally having good knowledge of Symfony and being able to look thru the code is a must for Sylius. Probably gonna have headaches otherwise,  I wouldn't recommend it to complete Symfony neophytes, that framework has enough of a learning curve already.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm going to look into that. I hope to have a lot of chances this time hihihi. Regarding symfony, I was doing pretty well with version 4. Here I am just learning version 5